# Data not inserted in Sqlitedatabase

Tags: android, database, android-sqlite

I want to insert some values in a table of database. There is no error in logcat but still values are not inserted in the table. I am not able to identify the problem.

Here is the Database Class.
**FoodieDatabase.java**

```
public class FoodieDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

       public String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "
               + TableData.TableInfo.TABLE_NAME + "("
               + TableData.TableInfo.COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER primary key ,"
               + TableData.TableInfo.COLUMN_hostel + " TEXT not null,"
               + TableData.TableInfo.COLUMN_weekday + " TEXT not null,"
               + TableData.TableInfo.COLUMN_category + " TEXT not null,"
               + TableData.TableInfo.COLUMN_food + " TEXT not null,"
               + TableData.TableInfo.COLUMN_rate + " TEXT not null" + ")";


        private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

        // Database creation sql statement
        public FoodieDatabase(Context context) {
            super(context, TableData.TableInfo.DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            Log.w("FoodieDatabase","Database Created");
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
                    database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
            Log.w(FoodieDatabase.class.getName(),
                    " Table " + TableData.TableInfo.TABLE_NAME + " Successfully created. "
            );
        }
        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        }

        public void insertvalues(FoodieDatabase fdb, Integer id, String hostel,
                                 String weekday, String category, String food , String rate ){
            SQLiteDatabase sdb = fdb.getWritableDatabase();

            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put(TableData.TableInfo.COLUMN_ID,id);
            cv.put(TableData.TableInfo.COLUMN_hostel,hostel );
            cv.put(TableData.TableInfo.COLUMN_weekday,weekday );
            cv.put(TableData.TableInfo.COLUMN_category,category );
            cv.put(TableData.TableInfo.COLUMN_food,food );
            cv.put(TableData.TableInfo.COLUMN_rate,rate );

            sdb.insert(TableData.TableInfo.TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
        }

        public Cursor retrievevalues(FoodieDatabase fdb){

            SQLiteDatabase sq = fdb.getReadableDatabase();
            String[] columns = {TableData.TableInfo.COLUMN_ID,
                    TableData.TableInfo.COLUMN_hostel,
                    TableData.TableInfo.COLUMN_weekday,
                    TableData.TableInfo.COLUMN_category,
                    TableData.TableInfo.COLUMN_food,
                    TableData.TableInfo.COLUMN_rate};
            Cursor CR = sq.query(TableData.TableInfo.TABLE_NAME,columns,null,null,null,null,null);
            return CR;
        }
    }
```

**InsertData.java**

```
public class InsertData extends AppCompatActivity {
    com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText sno;
    com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText hostel;
    com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText category;
    com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText food;
    com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText weekday;
    com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText rate;


    Button insert;

    String Shostel;
    String Scategory;
    String Sfood;
    String Sweekday;
    String Srate;

    Integer Isno;

    Context context= this;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_insert_data);

        sno = (com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText) findViewById(R.id.sno);
        sno.setText("1");
        hostel = (com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText) findViewById(R.id.hostel);
        category = (com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText) findViewById(R.id.category);
        food = (com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText) findViewById(R.id.food);
        weekday = (com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText) findViewById(R.id.weekday);
        rate = (com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText) findViewById(R.id.rate);

        insert = (Button) findViewById(R.id.insert);

        Isno = Integer.parseInt(sno.getText().toString());
        Shostel = hostel.getText().toString();
        Scategory = category.getText().toString();
        Sfood = food.getText().toString();
        Sweekday = weekday.getText().toString();
        Srate = rate.getText().toString();

        insert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FoodieDatabase fdb = new FoodieDatabase(context);
                fdb.insertvalues(fdb,Isno,Shostel,Sweekday,Scategory,Sfood,Srate);
                Toast.makeText(InsertData.this,"Value No." + Isno + Shostel + Scategory + "inserted successfully.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                Intent intent = new Intent(InsertData.this, Home.class);
                InsertData.this.startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
```

In **InsertData.java** file I have used Toast to check that values like `Isno` , `Shostel`, `Scategory`.  `Shostel`, `Scategory` values are null in toast. I mean they are blank, nothing is shown. While `Isno`  always shows `1`which I have set in that `editText` initially.
Do tell me if you need more details. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Why do you come to the conclusion nothing is inserted and what do you mean by that exactly? Is your table still empty or is your conclusion based on the values in your toast? Nowhere are you retrieving the valuyes from the database, so how can you be sure nothing is inserted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are storing the values before the user even sees the UI.  You should put the values from your EditTexts after you get the click --

```
    insert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Isno = Integer.parseInt(sno.getText().toString());
            Shostel = hostel.getText().toString();
            Scategory = category.getText().toString();
            Sfood = food.getText().toString();
            Sweekday = weekday.getText().toString();
            Srate = rate.getText().toString();

            FoodieDatabase fdb = new FoodieDatabase(context);
            fdb.insertvalues(fdb,Isno,Shostel,Sweekday,Scategory,Sfood,Srate);
            Toast.makeText(InsertData.this,"Value No." + Isno + Shostel + Scategory + "inserted successfully.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            Intent intent = new Intent(InsertData.this, Home.class);
            InsertData.this.startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    });
```